# iOS - get heading and inclination of device's Z axis

Tags: ios, objective-c, position, heading

I'm trying to get the heading and the inclination of the Z axis (screen) of the device, in whatever position the device is (i.e. landscape, portrait, or other).

Through the following code I can get the heading from the Y axis (top of the device), but can't figure out how to change the axis:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    _heading  = (float) manager.heading.magneticHeading;
}
```

And by the following code I can get the inclination, but only on landscape mode, not in every position:

```
_inclination = fabsf(self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.roll);
```

I made some experiments with a rotation matrix, from the apple's sample code **pARk**, but I'm struggling with the mathematics. The best I could do was getting the heading of the Z axis but only when the device is in landscape:

```
CMRotationMatrix r = d.attitude.rotationMatrix;
        transformFromCMRotationMatrix(cameraTransform, &r);
        _heading = (M_PI + atan2(r.m32, r.m22))*180/M_PI;
```

Can someone give me a help achieving this ?

Many thanks.